# three.js using points to make smoke effect

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I want to make a smoke effect like this [demo (Smoke)](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Particle-Engine.html) by using points. Now I have two problems.

1. At the beginning of the animation, all points get together and go up together like cloud.
2. the shape of the effect looks like a rectangular prism. How to make it looks like a cone (like the following picture)?

Can somebody please tell me how to fix these problems? Thanks!

[image]

```js
let renderer, scene, camera;
let controls, stats;

// points
const particleCount = 500;
let points;

function createPoints() {
 const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

 const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/images/smokeparticle.png');
 let material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 15,
  map: texture,
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  depthWrite: false,
  transparent: true,
  color: 'rgb(30,30,30)'
 });

 const range = 10;
 for (let i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
  const x = THREE.Math.randInt(-range, range);
  const y = THREE.Math.randInt(-range, range);
  const z = THREE.Math.randInt(-range, range);
  const point = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
  point.velocityX = THREE.Math.randFloat(-0.01, 0.01);
  point.velocityY = THREE.Math.randFloat(0.1, 0.3);
  geometry.vertices.push(point);
 }

 points = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
 scene.add(points);
}

function init() {
 // scene
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
 scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0x000000, 0.0008);

 // camera
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
 camera.position.set(0, 10, 170);
 camera.lookAt(scene.position);


 let axes = new THREE.AxesHelper(20);
 scene.add(axes);

 // renderer
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);


 // OrbitControls
 controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

 createPoints();

 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function pointsAnimation() {
 points.geometry.vertices.forEach(function(v) {
  v.y = v.y + v.velocityY;
  v.x = v.x + v.velocityX;

  if (v.y >= 100) v.y = 0;
 });

 points.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
}

function render() {
 pointsAnimation();
 requestAnimationFrame(render);
 controls.update();
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});

init();
render();
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/104/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set `velocityX` depending on point x, e.g. :

```
point.velocityX = THREE.Math.randFloat(0.0, 0.1) * Math.sign(x);
```

Don't forget to reset x position :

```
if (v.y >= 100) {
  v.x = THREE.Math.randInt(-10, 10);
  v.y = 0;
}
```